# How to extend partition with unallocated space?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have currently cloned my old SSD to a bigger SSD which resulted in that the exact size of the partition table cloned to it, instead of using the full space. I've tried with gparted to extend it but can't seem to do it. I am currently running it on a live Ubuntu usb.

[image]

how do I extend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using LVM (the logical volume manager) for your system, there are some ways to do that. You could create a new (primary) partition in the free space and add it to the LVM device. Or first extend the "extended partition" (`/dev/sdb2`), then create a new logical partition and extend the LVM then.

I'd recommend the following steps:

In `GParted`, first extend the "extended partition" `/dev/sdb2` to use the whole disk, and after that extend `/dev/sdb5` to use the whole extended partition.

Restart your system then, running the installed OS (not the live system). You now have to work with the different stages of LVM. If you are not very used to the linux commandline, I suggest to install the package `system-config-lvm` by `sudo apt install system-config-lvm`. This gives you a graphical interface to the LVM configuration. You can start this by running `system-config-lvm` from the commandline or selecting the application in your system menu.

As I do not currently use LVM on my system, I cannot give you more advice how to use this tool (e.g. with screenshots). But if you come so far and have additional problems/questions, just address a comment to this answer. If you prefer to use the commandline tools, I could give you more hints then.

Comment: I guess `/dev/sdb` is the one my system is using...  and yes it seems like LVM, sot sure how that occurred... I will give the gui a try.

Comment: When installing Ubuntu, it usually creates LVM patition by default. And yes, It's /dev/sdb - I will correct my answer.

Comment: I've extended it using gparted.. I just deactivate the partition , and the resized it to fit the full size. why should i do the LVM?

Comment: ok... something is wrong ... i cannot start on the new ubuntu partition..
`Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary`

Comment: What do you mean with "deactivate the partition"? Can you show a sceenshot of the gparted display as it looks now? Why can't you start ubuntu again?

Comment: I did the LVM part from live system and i worked..

Answer (score 0):

In GParted, right click on the partition you would like to extend (`/dev/sdb5` in this case) and select the option "**Resize/Move**". Then, set the ticker box labeled "**Free space following (MiB)**" to 0.

Comment: they aren't connected